# Biholomorphic self maps of certain domains $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Give an explicit description of all the biholomorphic self maps of
>   $\Omega$, for:
>
> 1. $\Omega = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0 \}$.
> 2. $\Omega = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{P_1,\ldots,P_k \}$.

(Greene and Krantz, *Function Theory of One Complex Variable* (3rd ed.), Ch 6, Problem 5, rephrased)

**My thoughts:** For part 1, one may reason as follows. We know that the biholomorphic self maps of $\mathbb{C}$ are the linear transformations $$ f(z) = az+b, \; (a\ne 0).$$
Of these, we only want those that preserve $0$, which means functions of the form $z\mapsto az$.

**Edit:** Having seen Arthur's remark, there are additional biholomorphic self map in the form
$$ z \mapsto \frac{a}{z}, \;\; (a\ne 0).$$

In part 2, trying to generalize to $k$ points, it's clear that the only linear function that preserves even two points is just the identity. But we may find linear functions that permute the set $\{P_1,\ldots,P_k\}$. Any ideas on how to continue ?

Comment: If you consider instead of $\Bbb C$, the Riemann sphere, any biholomorphic function on the sphere, preserving the set $\{0, \infty\}$, would fit (1). You only found half of them.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. You're right.

Comment: what do you mean by preserve $0$?

Comment: and would you tell me the answer of $2$?

Comment: @Tsotsi: Preserve $0$ means fix $0$, or explicitly $f(0)=0$. The idea to generalize from the first part is that any such biholomorphic map acts as a permutation on $P_1,\ldots,P_k, \infty$. Hence, if $k=2$, one can cook up a Mobius trasformation for each of the 6 permutations. If, however, $k>2$, one cannot generally do so, and the only biholomorphic map would be the identity.