Conformal equivalence and Automorphisms
If $U,V\subset \mathbb C_\infty$ - conformally equivalent domains, I know that $\textrm{Aut}(U)\simeq \textrm{Aut}(V)$ in group sense. Is converse true? If yes - please provide a source to read about it, if not, could you please provide an example?

Maybe see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216814/biholomorphic-self-maps-of-certain-domains-omega-subseteq-mathbbc. I believe if the last comment is true, then you can just choose V and U to be the complex plane that miss $k$ and $k+1$ points respectively ($k \ge 4$) , then they both have trivial automorphism group, but they are not biholomorphic. Though I think that comment should be true, I haven't tried proving it though.

For any annulus the automorphism group is $\mathbb S^1\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ where for any $|\alpha|=1$ we have the map $z \to \alpha z$ and then we have the inversion $z \to rR/z$ where the annulus is $r<|z|<R$ and the two do not commute if $\alpha$ not real (hence the semidirect product). See Automorphism group of Annulus for a sketch of a proof.
But annuli conformally depend on one parameter (the ratio between the outer and inner radius) so $1<|z|<2$ and $1<|z|<3$ for example are not conformally equivalent but have the same automorphism group.
When we take domains with finitely many holes but more than $1$ the results are less precise in the sense that it is known that the automorphism groups of such are finite groups with cardinality at most $2k$ when there are $k \ne 4,6,8,12,20, k \ge 2$ holes and specific numbers for the exceptions. But domains with $k \ge 1$ holes are conformally parametrized by $3k-2$ parameters so since there are finitely many groups of size at most the corresponding number for $k$ holes, infinitely many such will have same automorphism group without being conformally equivalent.
See Chapter $12$ in S. Krantz Geometric Function Theory for more details.
